# Condition IF for when a calendar day is equal to a number

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I have a date in a cell set to display only the day. For example, if the date is March 3, 2020 it only shows 3. Then I need to apply an `IF` function for when a number matches that calendar day. But the sheet does not take the coincidence because it interprets that the "3" is actually "March 3, 2020". How can I make it interpret only the number displayed (3) and not the entire date?

Comment: `=IF(DAY(A1)=5, "yes", "no")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if only day is displayed you can use **`=INDIRECT("A1")`**

[image: 0]

otherwise, you can use **`=DAY(A1)`**

[image: 000]